# multiplexing between two topic

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am using P3AT(USARSim simulator) and want to drive it from my **ROS-Fuerte**. what i want to do is,

1. Driving the robot using keyboard (using teleop_twist_keyboard)
2. Automated navigation of robot (using Navigation stack)

I want to drive the robot using keyboard but when i commit mistake(i.e. approaching to hit a wall) the automated behavior need to be activated.

by following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux), i have my configuration file

**example_cfg.yaml**

```
subscribers:
  - name:        "Human_is_Driving"
    topic:       "teleop_cmd_vel"
    timeout:     0.5
    priority:    5
  - name:        "MACHINE_TAKES_OVER"
    topic:       "auto_cmd_vel"
    timeout:     0.5
    priority:    5
publisher:       "velocity_multiplexer/mux_cmd_vel"
```

**standalone.launch**

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager"/>
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="velocity_multiplexer" args="load cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet nodelet_manager">
    
    <param name="subscribers_cfg_file" value="$(find cmd_vel_mux)/param/example_cfg1.yaml"/>
    
    <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/mux_cmd_vel" to="mobile_base/commands/velocity"/>
    <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/web_cmd_vel" to="web_app_teleop"/>
    <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/key_cmd_vel" to="key_cmd_vel"/>
    <remap from="velocity_multiplexer/amcl_pose" to="amcl_pose" />
    <remap from="velocity_multiplexer/move_base_simple/goal" to="move_base_simple/goal" />
    
  </node>
</launch>
```

**resulting rqt graphs of**

1. [teleoperation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91x7g395wb2n10i/rqt_graph_teleop.png?dl=0)
2. [automated navigation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqcy1vnzwxobi92/rqt_graph_move_base.png?dl=0)

i am not able to understand the complexity of the problem.

please help me to understand ***"how can i switch between cmd_vel used by teleop & cmd_vel used by move_base"***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195524/multiplexing-between-two-topic/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the assisted_teleop package: http://wiki.ros.org/assisted_teleop

It isn't documented, but there are a few sample launch files like https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/blob/hydro-devel/assisted_teleop/launch/assisted_teleop.launch

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2014-10-22**:
@ahendrix thank you for reply

i have read about cmd_vel_mux, can we use it for the same purpose.
i am also using the same. but not able to write the launch file.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-22**:
cmd_vel_mux allows switching between topics, but is generally useful in the cases where manual control should preempt autonomous control; not the other way around.